# Reload page's JavaScript after editing HTML in Web Inspector

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-inspector

I'm editing a friend's site using a CMS's WYSIWYG editor - in the HTML source (viewed by clicking a button like  or something), I added a `<script></script>` tag with some JavaScript in. However, this JavaScript had a tiny error (I missed out a semi-colon or something) so it now has an error. When I try and load the WYSIWWG editor again, it doesn't show the toolbar with the Source Editor button anymore, as it was controlled by JS, and because there is a fatal JS error on the page, none of the JS works. So I can't access the HTML source now to correct my error.

I've tried to edit the HTML source in the Chrome Web Inspector to correct my error, but unlike with editing JS, you can't save HTML locally in the Web Inspector and then reload with your changes. Do you have any idea how I could fix this? All I need to be able to do is get the JS working and then I can go in, press the HTML source button in the Editor and correct my error permanently. Something else I thought of was correcting my error in the DOM Tree, and then reloading the JS via the Web Inspector console or something, and hopefully the toolbar would appear, now that the inline JS is correct.

Comment: Why don't you correct the HTML in web inspector and then call the function that brings toolbar through your chrome console?

Comment: I can't find the function, that's the problem. The JS is quite difficult to read as it's hugely long. I'll continue looking though.

Comment: So you are saying that the WYSIWYG editor has executed your script code...? Thats not very good. There is no way around it, and modifying javascript after load is not allowed (as this would allow me to just hijack any page and use it to legitimately send code to the server as if it was intended to do so). I think your best option is likely to disable the WYSYWIG editor and modify the textarea that feeds its input.

Comment: You know, you could just copy and paste the entire js thingy. Just saying.